# I have release alpha version of my android app on play console. Do i need to release another version for closed test? or should i wait till approval?

Tags: java, android, app-store, google-play-console

I have uploaded alpha version on play console it's showing in review. So will i wait till approval or will release another version for closed test.

I uploaded Alpha release 30th December 2023.

Thanks in Adavnce

I don't have any information about this issue.

Comment: You can create any amount of test track as you want - alpha, beta, internal etc. Each time you upload a new build into any of these tracks, it will be reviewed (in parallel, they don't block each other). If you want to upload a new build to another track - go ahead. If you want to upload a new build to the same track - your previous one will become "unavailable" for end users, so it's better to wait until approval. If you don't care about this build, then yes, you can upload a new one.